# Why is the ui.Thumbnail not generated?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, thumbnail

I am generating a image consisting of 3 bands and would like to generate a thumbnail from it. Unfortunately the thumbnail is not displayed, only a placeholder is shown.

[image: png thumbnail placeholder]

My script is the following ([Script in Earth Engine Code Editor](https://code.earthengine.google.com/99372ba4b4d73269d7029682fcd76844))

```
var europe_bbox = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-12.222935630617995, 47.34321448670071],
      [-12.222935630617995, 34.021613745857614],
      [7.288783119382005, 34.021613745857614],
      [7.288783119382005, 47.34321448670071]]], null, false);

// Make a black background image
var background = ee.Image(0).visualize({palette: '000000'});

// Make a grey Europe outline
var addID = function(feature) { return feature.set({ID: 1});};

var europe = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017')
           .filter(ee.Filter.eq('wld_rgn', 'Europe'))
           .map(addID);

// Create an image from the feature collection
var europeImg = europe.reduceToImage(['ID'], ee.Reducer.first());

//Make the tree loss layer
var treeLoss = ee.Image('UMD/hansen/global_forest_change_2019_v1_7').select('lossyear');

// Blend background - dark europe outline - tree loss layer
treeLoss = treeLoss.visualize({ palette: ['yellow', 'red'], min: 0, max: 19});

var composite = background.blend(europeImg).blend(treeLoss);

print(ui.Thumbnail(composite,
 {format: 'PNG', dimensions: 2000, region: europe_bbox, crs:'EPSG:3035'}));
```

Does anyone know why this happens and what I may be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no argument crs in the ui.Thumbnail, commenting it out should make the script work: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6ac90c2779e8eefe40bec733afb9986a.

Getting the thumbnail generated in EPSG:3035 is a bit more tricky in EE, you will need to fiddle a bit with projections, making sure the region fits into your AOI (rectangle in EPSG:3857 won't look the same in EPSG:3035), this code should give you a hint on how this can be done: https://code.earthengine.google.com/c27cb0b665e6bdbaa710cf7ad373e6ec

```js
var scale = 5000

composite = composite
  .blend(ee.FeatureCollection([europe_bbox]).style({width:2, color: '00ffff', fillColor: '00000000'}))
  .reproject(ee.Projection('EPSG:4326').atScale(scale))
  .changeProj(
    ee.Projection('EPSG:3035').translate(3400000, -2000000).scale(100000, 100000),
    ee.Projection('EPSG:4326')
)

Map.addLayer(composite, { min: 0, max: 255}, 'reprojected')

composite = composite.reproject(ee.Projection('EPSG:4326').atScale(scale))

print(ui.Thumbnail(composite, {
  format: 'PNG', 
  dimensions: 2000, 
  region: europe_bbox, 
}));
```

[image]